# When exactly is a connection to MySQL server secure?

Tags: ssl, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm trying to understand the exact meaning of SSL while trying to connect to a MySQL server (via mysql-connector-python). I have MySQL (v5.7) setup locally and I have 2 users. One (root) is the default user and the other user (ssl_user) has `REQUIRE SSL` option enabled. If I try to connect to ssl_user with the following config, I get an error saying ssl_user does not have access.

```
mysql_conf = {
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': '3306',
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '',
    'ssl_disabled': True #Default value is False    
}
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_conf)
```

I'm able to connect to the MySQL if I change the value as `'ssl_disabled': False` but the value of `conn.is_secure` is `False`.

I also have a Google Cloud SQL instance with SSL certificates configured. With the following config, I'm able to connect to the Cloud SQL instance

```
mysql_config = {
    'host': '<cloud_SQL_IP>',
    'port': '3306',
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'admin@123',
    'database': 'test_database',
    'ssl_ca': '/Users/<username>/Downloads/server-ca.cer',
    'ssl_cert': '/Users/<username>/Downloads/client-cert.cer',
    'ssl_key': '/Users/<username>/Downloads/client-key.cer',
    'ssl_disabled': False,
    'ssl_verify_cert': True,
}
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
```

With the above configuration, I'm able to connect to MySQL but my `conn.is_secure` is still `False`.

I'm not able to understand what exactly is the difference between connection via `'ssl_disabled': False` and connecting by providing SSL certificates? Is the certificate just an extra layer of security?

Comment: I looked through the code of mysql-connector, and it looks like `is_secure` should be true when you use `ssl_disabled: False`

Comment: I also looked through the code of mysql-connector, and I tried a bunch of experiments. As far as I tested, I got `Ssl_cipher` to indicate it's a secure connection (it would be NULL on an unencrypted connection). But I could not get the `is_secure` property in the Python connector to be set unless I connected via `unix_socket`, in which case TLS is moot, and it's secure by virtue of not using TCP.

Comment: can anyone tell me what an user created with ssl require params mean?, do pymsql connect to mysql server via an encrypted connection? if, how does it work